# Python Django TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to setup my database using `dj_database`; however, I am getting a `TypeError`:

```py
db_from_env = dj_database_url(conn_max_age=600)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The code that the traceback is calling is

```py
db_from_env = dj_database_url(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASE['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

If you have any knowledge on why this would be happening the help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a typo. The docs show you should be likely calling a `config` function: `dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate this worked, not sure why I did this wrong in the first place but thanks :)